# abstract target causing wrong output folder name

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, podfile

I'm trying to setup multiple variants for my React Native project (expo on bare workflow), I'm using the eas official documentation to do it (https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variants/)

As the documentation says I wrapped my original podfile target code inside an `abstract_target` and it end up like this

```rb
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/package.json')"`), "native_modules")

platform :ios, '12.0'

require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read('./Podfile.properties.json')) rescue {}

abstract_target 'common' do
  use_expo_modules!
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes'
  )


  target 'LoperDEVELOP' do
  end

  target 'LoperSTAGING' do
  end
  
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if (target.name&.eql?('FBReactNativeSpec'))
        target.build_phases.each do |build_phase|
          if (build_phase.respond_to?(:name) && build_phase.name.eql?('[CP-User] Generate Specs'))
            target.build_phases.move(build_phase, 0)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  post_integrate do |installer|
    begin
      expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
  end
end
```

everything looks well, until the compiler fails with the following error:

> Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-LoperDEVELOP/ExpoModulesProvider.swift

After checking the temporal generated folder it looks to be created with the wrong name after the addition of the `abstract_target`

now the output folder is

> /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/**Pods-common-LoperDEVELOP**/ExpoModulesProvider.swift

and the expected is

> /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/**Pods-LoperDEVELOP**/ExpoModulesProvider.swift

As you can see, in the LoperDevelop folder it is concatenating `Pods-{abstract_target}-{target}` when the compiler expects just `Pods-{target}`

Am i doing something wrong? or it's any workaround to this situation?

Edit:
Add a little more info to the problem.
when I execute `pod install` in ios folder the pods are installed without any problems.

but after that, when i ran `expo run:ios` it produces a fail because it is looking for `ExpoModulesProvider.swift` in `Pods-LoperDEVELOP` folder instead of `Pods-common-LoperDevelop` (which is created using `abstract target 'common'`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is solved.

It was a miss configuration in XCode, if someone has in the same situation, you have to go to the following section

XCode -> Specific Target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources

[image]

And inside it, make sure that all the files are correct, In my case, there were a file with a wrong path causing the entire issue